# My search works but if lots of words are used it returns tons of non related things

Tags: php, javascript, sql

My search works but if lots of words are used it returns tons of non related things. Any ideas as to how to fix the search to where if long phrases are searched it will pull a narrower result and not more stuff. this function I think may be searching each keyword for each individual articles title and im not sure whats wrong with it

```
function search_results($search_for) {
$returned_results = array();
$where = "";

$search_for = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $search_for);
$total_search_words = count($search_for);

foreach($search_for as $key=>$search_term) {
    $where .= "`review_title` LIKE '%$search_term%'";

    if($key != ($total_search_words - 1)) {
        $where .= " OR ";
    }
}
$value = $_POST['search_value'];
$results = "SELECT * FROM `reviews` WHERE `review_referral` = '$value' AND $where";
$results_num = ($results = mysql_query($results)) ? mysql_num_rows($results) : 0;

if($results_num === 0) {
    return false;
} else {

    while($results_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        $returned_results[] = array(
                            'review_title' => $results_row['review_title'],
                            'review_body' => $results_row['review_body'],
                            'user_id' => $results_row['user_id'],
                            'user_firstname' => $results_row['user_firstname'],
                            'user_lastname' => $results_row['user_lastname'],
                            'review_id' => $results_row['review_id'],
                            'review_body' => $results_row['review_body'],
                            'review_referral' => $results_row['review_referral'],
                            'rating' => $results_row['rating'],
                            'review_date' => $results_row['review_date'],
                            'review_category' => $results_row['review_category'],
                            'review_url' => $results_row['review_url'],
                            'referral_category' => $results_row['referral_category'],
        );

    }

return $returned_results;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to narrow down searches you should use AND instead of OR.

```
if($key != ($total_search_words - 1)) {
    $where .= " AND ";
}
```

Comment: If you want to make the search return all possible variations, but show the relevant results at the top, you could rank your results to show the ones with AND matches at the top of the results, or use specific fields within the database as being more relevant (such as search terms in the review_title field being more important than in the review_body). When writing a custom search like this, if you know your tables well, you can easily have the best results go to the top of the list - making your search better overall.